# Adding scrollbar to a Group in AX 2012 form

Tags: x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to set scrollbar in a Group as shown below since there are many more vertical fast tabs are available which are getting hide when opening any tab as you can see below . I have used tab and selected style as Fasttab. I have tried to set Scrollbar property of tab and its tabpages to yes but for no result.

[image: Scrollbar add]

Any help would be great!!!

Comment: What is the height property of the tab?

Comment: That's good to hear, could you add an answer to help out anyone else who is having the same issue and finds this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. by setting height and width properties correctly. properties are:

Group:-

Height:column width
    width :column width

Tab:-

Height:column width
    width :column width

Tabpages:

Height:Auto
    width :column width

That's it!!

Answer (score 2):

I have perfect solution  :)

Add a new Group in the from. Nothing in it.

```
Set HideEmpty=false.  
Set Height=ColumnHeight, Width=ColumnWidth

Set forms Height=Auto, Width=Auto.
```

### That is all.

Form can be `Re-size`,  the scroll bar shows.

Comment: This hid my ActionPane