# DirPartyQuickCreateForm change scroll

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to resize this form, I changed the "WindowsResize" dynamic property.

I've also added a scroll, but the probem is that the scroll not reach the Save button.

Can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change design properties **Width** and **Height** property from **Auto** to **Column width** (height)?

Sometimes it is needed to change this properties on all design parts that are needed to change size with form size.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414807/adding-scrollbar-to-a-group-in-ax-2012-form)

Comment: Yes, this example may help you understand more what I want.

I have the form I show at the following URL

i61.tinypic.com/sevecz.png

When I change the size, the scroll bar does not drop down to the buttons.

i62.tinypic.com/28i6ek8.png

It is a similiar example of what happens to me "DirPartyQuickCreateForm"

I do not know if I will have explained well.

A greeting.

Comment: Looks like the scroll is on the wrong group. One thing I would try would be adding a group and add all other group into it. Where is a point you open this form from? There also may be some parameters on menuitems/menuitembuttons/buttons etc. but they should not affect this.